# Como criar uma variável de id a partir de um resultado de uma query?

Tags: sql

Eu estou fazendo uma query de uma tabela que não tem um variável `id`, mas gostaria de atribuir um `id` ao meu resultado. Segue exemplo:

**Base de exemplo:**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE breaking;
use breaking;
CREATE TABLE characters (name VARCHAR(100), sex VARCHAR(100), age VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO characters (name,sex,age)
VALUES ("W. White","male",54);
INSERT INTO characters (name,sex,age)
VALUES ("Hank Schroder","male",51);
INSERT INTO characters (name,sex,age)
VALUES ("Gus Fring","male",50);
INSERT INTO characters (name,sex,age)
VALUES ("Skyler","female",44);
```

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT name
FROM breaking.characters
WHERE sex='male'
```

Retorna:

```
+---------------+
| name          |
+---------------+
| W. White      |
| Hank Schroder |
| Gus Fring     |
+---------------+
```

Para criar a variável de `id` no output, eu tentei:

```sql
SELECT 1 as id, name
FROM breaking.characters
WHERE sex='male'
```

Que retorna:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | W. White      |
|  1 | Hank Schroder |
|  1 | Gus Fring     |
+----+---------------+
```

O problema dessa solução é que ela atribuí o mesmo id para todo mundo. Como faço para obter ids diferentes? Em particular, gostaria que os ids fossem uma sequência de número de mesmo cumprimento do resultado. Nesse caso, tenho três nomes como resultado, então gostaria de ids=[1,2,3].

Tentei ainda:

```sql
SELECT (1,2,3) as id, name
FROM breaking.characters
WHERE sex='male'
```

Mas não funcionou também.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS id, name
FROM breaking.characters
WHERE sex='male'
```

Comment: sua solução está correta, mas evite postar apenas o código da resposta. Se possível, adicione uma explicação para o código. Veja instruções em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer